# Rendering several sprites from the same texture in SDL 2.0 with C++

Tags: c++, textures, rendering, sdl, sprite

I'm trying to make a Puyo Puyo game. It's a puzzle. Which means that many of the same sprites will appear at the same time. I get to render the four types of sprites. But, when the first one finishes falling, the next sprites flicker and the game begins to lag.

I have read about grouping the fallen sprites to one texture, so they work as a single texture and I think with LockTexture it might work. But I don't know how to use it.

Here's my code:

```
//While application is running
while( !quit )
{
    //Get objects from list (Deque).
    puyo* p=list_puyo.at(c_list);
    p->move=true;
    getSpriteClip(p);
    //printf(c_list+": y:"+p.y);

    //Characters that haven't reached bottom continue to fall.
    if(p->move &&!p->bottom)
        fallingPuyo(p); //Every 512 miliseconds, the character will fall 32 pixels.

    //Handle events on queue
    while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
    {
        //User requests quit
        if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
        {
            quit = true;
        }

    }
    //Set texture based on current keystate


    const Uint8* currentKeyStates = SDL_GetKeyboardState( NULL );
    if(!p->bottom && p->move)
    {

        if( currentKeyStates[ SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN ] )
        {

            if(!collisionCheck(false,false,p))
            {
                pressedKey++;
                if(pressedKey>128)
                {
                    p->y+=32;
                    pressedKey=0;
                }
            }

        }
        else if( currentKeyStates[ SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT ] )
        {
            if(!collisionCheck(true,false,p))
            {
                pressedKey++;
                if(pressedKey>128)
                {
                    p->x-=32;
                    pressedKey=0;
                }
            }
        }
        else if( currentKeyStates[ SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT ] )
        {
            if(!collisionCheck(false,true,p))
            {
                pressedKey++;
                if(pressedKey>128)
                {
                    p->x+=32;
                    pressedKey=0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Clear screen
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );
    SDL_RenderClear( gRenderer );

    gBackgroundTexture.render(0,0); //window background

    gBoardTexture.render(SCREEN_WIDTH/4+30,0); //board background

    gSpriteSheetTexture.render( p->x, p->y, p->gSpriteClips); //puyos render

    //Update screen
    SDL_RenderPresent( gRenderer );

    //Return puyo to list
    list_puyo.at(c_list)=p;

    //Increment list counter by one.
    c_list++;

    //return counter to 0.
    if(c_list>=list_puyo.size())
        c_list=0;

}
}
}
```

Comment: Wait, it only starts flickering after one falls? Or after you add a second one? If you don't double buffer, you might want to do that, because flickering is usually a symptom of not double buffering.

Comment: Are you doing all this for one iteration of the list or am I interpreting your code wrongly?

Comment: No, @olevegard, what happens is if the list counter becomes bigger than the list itself, the counter returns to zero. I'm going through all the objects of the list.

Comment: @BWG, how do I use double buffer?

Comment: @ElAramu Well, you might be already double buffering. I've not used SDL graphics. But I see some other weird stuff going on in your code. For example, this whole thing is your main loop. Yet you only ever act on one puyo per loop. And then, you 'return' it to the list. That is unnecessary, because `p` is a pointer, not an instance, so returning it just sets the pointer in your list back to what it was before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//you want a "global" list of input, so you don't have to check only in input
bool keyLeftPressed = false;
bool keyRightPressed = false;
bool keyDownPressed = false;

//this controls how long before your player can move the puyo again
//so you don't have to do a hacky method in your keypressing code
int controlCooldown = 0;
while( !quit ) {
    //this little if makes your cooldown go back to zero slowly
    if(controlCooldown > 0) {
        controlCooldown--;
    }

    //Handle events on queue
    while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ) {
        //User requests quit
        if( e.type == SDL_QUIT ) {
            quit = true;
        } elsef if(e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) { //all events (including keypress) go in the event loop
            if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_DOWN) {
                keyDownPressed = true;
            } if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LEFT) {
                keyLeftPressed = true;
            } if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RIGHT) {
                keyRightPressed = true;
            }
        } else if(e.type == SDL_KEYUP) {//key release, set them back to false
            if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_DOWN) {
                keyDownPressed = false;
            } if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LEFT) {
                keyLeftPressed = false;
            } if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RIGHT) {
                keyRightPressed = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //you need to iterate every puyo every frame, not just one
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < list_puyo.size(); i++) {
        puyo* p = list_puyo.at(i);
        if(p->move &&!p->bottom) {
            fallingPuyo(p);
        }
        if(controlCooldown >= 0) {
            if(keyLeftPressed) {
                p->x-=32;
                controlCooldown = 128;
            } else if(keyRightPressed) {
                p->x+=32;
                controlCooldown = 128;
            } else if(keyDownPressed) {
                p->y+=32;
                controlCooldown = 128;
            }
            //if any key was pressed, they now have to wait 128 more cycles before it moves again
        }
        //i'm not sure how you want to render each puyo, or if you are already doing it
        renderPuyo(p);
    }


    //Clear screen
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );
    SDL_RenderClear( gRenderer );

    gBackgroundTexture.render(0,0); //window background

    gBoardTexture.render(SCREEN_WIDTH/4+30,0); //board background

    gSpriteSheetTexture.render( p->x, p->y, p->gSpriteClips); //puyos render

    //Update screen
    SDL_RenderPresent( gRenderer );

}
}
}
```

Alright, I'll give you a rundown of majorly what has been changed:

- Puyo logic (the solution to your question)
  The puyos all get iterated each frame, instead of just one per frame. This is why they were flickering before. This also fixes any actions they take.
- Cooldown for moving the puyo
  Instead of incrementing a value every time a key was pressed, it now increments every tick until 0 is reached. This is better, because if the user lightly taps a key and then quickly releases, the puyo had a very small chance of moving. This fixes the problem, by setting it to zero, and then passively decrementing every frame, not only when a key is held down
- Event queue
  I don't know *what* you were doing before, involving key strokes, but now there is a simple boolean value for each key of interest. There are two advantages to this:

  1. You can put logic code anywhere, not just in the input part
  2. You can have continuous key checks, not just as it is being pressed. If you *NEED* to check on click, just add in your old code

Of course, I'm just interpreting what your code does based on this fragment. If I got anything wrong, don't do it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, @BWG. It's strange, because I used a loop, before posting the code here where, to render all the puyos and it began to lag. But, now it doesn't. I used your key state changes. Now it works and it doesn't flicker.